# How to change a Netlify file after Build

Tags: netlify

Is it possible to change a file on Netlify after the site has already been built?

*Example:*

If I have a site:
https://physiome-test.netlify.com/simple_heart/ that accesses a file at

https://physiome-test.netlify.com/simple_heart/models/organsViewerModels/cardiovascular/heart/ecgAnimation.json

Is there any way that I can change this file without having to update my [github repository](https://github.com/Tehsurfer/MPB)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can change this file without having to update my github repository?

Using Netlify continuous deployment, which is what you are doing, you **can't just change one file** on Netlify without changing the files in your git repository that is tied to building your build process.

Process Netlify uses:

- On commit trigger (webhook from GitHub) or a `trigger deploy` in the `app.netlify.com` admin
- Checkout your target branch
- Runs your build command
- Compares your current build to existing CDN contents
- Updates global CDN for changed files in your target deploy location

### Changing Netlify Files without changing git

A new feature allows you to drag a deploy folder to `app.netlify.com` for fast review/deploy without using your git repository. Go to the `Deploys` tab of the site you want to update. You will see a message at the bottom like the pic below:

[image]

Drag your deploy folder to this location from your local system and your site will be updated with any new files on Netlify.

**Note:** **All** the files of your site must be in the folder with your current changes.

Answer (score 4):

The [`netlify-cli`](https://docs.netlify.com/cli/get-started/#deploy-directories) can deploy directories without modifying a git repo.

Here is an example usage:

```
npm run build
netlify status
netlify deploy
```

and if everything looks good on your draft URL, take it live with the `--prod` flag.

`netlify deploy --prod`

Everything will update automatically.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You can format your answers using backticks etc.

Comment: I am looking for the Update the file after manually deploy and found your answer and run all the command properly after running command netlify deploy, it asking for Please provide a publish directory (e.g. "public" or "dist" or "."): It is necessary to write 'dist'? If I don't write anything then? Currently I am using parcel in my react project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried NetlifyCMS? https://www.netlifycms.org/
You can edit content on Netlify and it is integrated to Git workflow.

Comment: Interesting, no I had not heard of netlifyCMS I'm having a look to see if it can edit content on Netlify via a javascript call

Comment: NetlifyCMS is for updating your git repository, not updating files on Netlify.

Comment: Anyone have a more updated answer? I do not see a drag and drop feature nor a feature to run a `netlify` command.